# When did the name “Boltzmann constant” prevail, and how?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

This question is prompted by (comments at) [another one](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/interpretation-of-w-in-boltzmanns-entropy-formula). There, I was surprised to find that despite traditional claims to the contrary, Boltzmann himself *did* once write his formula $S=k\log W$:

$\hspace{11em}$[image]

That’s in his book ([1898](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?30.0818.02), [§61, p. 172](https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenber02bolt#page/172)), with a pointer to ([1896](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?26.1056.06), [§8, p. 60](https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenber01bolt#page/60)) where he  says the same thing in words, and emphasizes that $RM$ is *the same constant for all gases*. In fact, if we note that his $R$ is the [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Molar_form) gas constant (equal to $P\ /\ \rho T$ by the gas law, p. 53) and his $M$ the molecular mass $\rho V\ /\ N$, we see on multiplying that his $RM$ is indeed our $PV\ /\ NT=k$. So all seems well.

But now: there is another common story, which we get to hear again as 2018 is the year the kelvin should be [redefined by freezing $k$](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2015.0037). E.g. White and Fischer ([2015](https://doi.org/10.1088/0026-1394/52/5/S213)) (emphasis mine):

> Although Boltzmann published his famous definition of entropy in [1877](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=hvd.32044093294908&num=373), the constant of proportionality in Boltzmann’s definition, was not identified as Boltzmann’s constant until 1900 when Planck published his analysis of blackbody radiation ([1900a](http://archive.org/stream/verhandlungende01goog#page/n212), [1900b](http://archive.org/stream/verhandlungende01goog#page/n247)), where he identified the constant as $k$ and **named it after Boltzmann**.

And that, again, seems not true. Of course Planck does introduce $k$ — in (1900b, p. 241), after $h$, as “a second constant of nature” such that an entropy is $k\log\mathfrak R_0$. But he does not name it after Boltzmann there — nor, unless I missed it, in any of the obvious or oft-quoted places. Not in the follow-up articles ([1901a](https://books.google.com/books?id=KhtbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA553), [1901b](https://books.google.com/books?id=KhtbAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA564)). Not in the Boltzmann *Festschrift* ([1904](https://archive.org/stream/festschriftludw00meyegoog#page/n133): no mention of $k$). Not in his books ([1906](https://archive.org/stream/uberdietheoewarm00planrich#page/n152), [1910](https://books.google.com/books?id=fjrQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA55&dq=%22Konstante%20k%22), [1913](https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberd01plangoog#page/n137), [1930](https://books.google.com/books?id=tMzPAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22universelle+Faktor+k%22)). Not in his Nobel lecture ([1920](https://archive.org/stream/MaxPlanckVortraegeRedenErinnerungen#page/n26)):

> This constant is frequently termed Boltzmann’s constant, although to the best of my knowledge **Boltzmann himself never introduced it**

Not in his autobiography ([1948](http://archive.org/stream/MaxPlanckVortraegeRedenErinnerungen#page/n69)) where $k$ is “the so-called absolute gas constant”. And most remarkably — even if meant with self-deprecating irony — not in his recollections ([1943](http://archive.org/stream/MaxPlanckVortraegeRedenErinnerungen#page/n24)):

> I (...) was not even taken seriously, in some places. But I did not let such doubts deter me from trusting **my constant** $k$.

The literature also seems to have settled slower than legend has it — see chronology in the CW answer below. (A name Planck *did* propose in (1900b, p. 245) is “Boltzmann-Drude constant” for $\alpha=3k/2$, but few besides Abraham ([1905](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?36.0906.02), [pp. 284, 362](https://archive.org/stream/142unkngoog#page/n375)) seem to have adopted it — e.g. Perrin ([1909](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uc1.31822017841578&num=18)) calls $\alpha$ “la constante d’énergie moleculaire”.)

So: If not in 1900, when did $k$ get its name? Was there ever a debate (e.g. after the unveiling of Boltzmann’s famous tombstone)? Was there a concerted decision? Were the above-quoted pages of Boltzmann’s book ever invoked? Or was it no-one’s doing, just [resolution by attrition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_principle)? Finally, if Planck did not *name the constant after Boltzmann*, how did we end up with the tale that he did?

Answer (score 7):

#### Community-wiki timeline of relevant literature:

By year written, sources where $k$ is named after...

[image: histogram]

`Author         |Dated    |Published |Denoted|Called 
 Boltzmann                 1877  (e)  ––   S  ein constanter Factor 1 
 Boltzmann•      1895.09   1896  (e)  RM   S  für alle Gase gleiche Constante RM 2 
 Boltzmann•      1898.08   1898  (e)  RM   S  –– 3 
 Drude           1900.02   1900       2α/3 E  –– (school using α = 3k/2 instead) 
 Planck          1900.12   1900b (e)  k    S  eine zweite Naturconstante 
 Planck          1901.01   1901a (e)  k    S  eine universelle Constante 
 Planck          1901.01   1901b (e)  k    S  die Strahlungsconstante k 
 Planck          1901.05   1901c      k    U  eine universelle positive Constante 
 Jeans           1901.06   1902       λ    R  the gas constant 
 Planck                    1901d      k    S  die Proportionalitätsconstante k 
 Einstein        1902.06   1902       2ϰ   E  eine universelle Constante 
 Lorentz         1903.04   1903       k    U  een universeele constante 
 Planck          1903.07   1904       ––      –– (Festschrift) 
 Einstein        1904.03   1904       2ϰ   E  eine absolute Konstante 
 Jeans•          1904.11   1904       R    E  an absolute constant 
 Abraham•        1905.03   1905       k    U  die universelle Konstante k 
 Einstein        1905.03   1905       C    S  eine universelle Konstante 4 
 Rayleigh        1905.05   1905       k    U  a constant 
 Jeans           1905.06   1905a      R    R  –– 
 Jeans           1905.07   1905b      k    S  –– 
 Jeans           1905.10   1905c      R    R  the constant of the theory of gases 
 Langevin                  1905a      r    R  constante de l’équation des gaz 
 Langevin                  1905b      r    R  constante de l’équation des gaz 
 Einstein        1906.03   1906a      R/N  R  –– 
 von Laue        1906.04   1906       k    U  Konstante des Verteilungsgesetzes 
 Planck•         1906.04   1906       k    S  universelle Integrationskonstante 
 Winkelmann•               1906       k    S  eine Konstante 
 Ehrenfest       1906.07   1906a      k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 5 
 Einstein        1906.08   1906b      k    S  eine (universelle) Konstante 
 Ehrenfest       1906.10   1906b      ––      –– (obituary) 
 Einstein        1906.12   1907       R/N  R  –– 6 
 von Laue        1907.03   1907a      k    U  Konstante des Planckschen Gesetzes 
 von Laue        1907.10   1907b      k    S  eine universelle Konstante 
 Reiche          1908.01   1908       k    U  eine gewisse allgemeine Konstante 
 Planck          1908.06   1908       k    S  –– 
 von Laue        1908.09   1908       k    S  eine universelle Konstante 
 Kowalski        1908.10   1908       k    U  Konstante des Planck’schen Gesetzes 
 Lorentz•        1909.01   1909       k    U  a universal physical constant
 Einstein        1909.01   1909a      R/N  R  –– 
 Reinganum       1909.04   1909       k    E  die Schwingungsenergie.. beträgt.. kT 
 Planck          1909.04   1910a (e)  k    S  die Konstante k 
 Wien•           1909.05   1909       k    S  –– 
 Jahn            1909.05   1909       k       die Plancksche Konstante 7
 Lorentz         1909.06   1909       2α/3 R  α -- een werkelijk universeele constante
 Einstein        1909.09   1909b      k    S  eine universelle Konstante 
 Larmor          1909.11   1909       k    S  a universal constant 
 Kowalski        1909.12   1910a      K       die universelle Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Planck          1910.01   1910b      k    U  eine Konstante 
 Haas            1910.03   1910       k    U  2/3 der Boltzmann-Drude’schen Konstanten 
 Kowalski        1910.05   1910b      k       la constante universelle de Boltzmann 
 Lindemann       1910.06   1910       k    U  –– 
 Debye           1910.10   1910a      k    S  universelle Konstante, welche.. 
 Einstein        1910.10   1910       R/N  R  –– 
 Debye           1910.10   1910b      k    S  –– 
 Einstein        1910.11   1911       k    U  Konst. der Planckschen Strahlungsformel 
 Planck          1911.02   1911a      k    S  –– 
 Planck          1911.04   1911b (g)  k    S  la constante k 
 Sommerfeld      1911.07   2004       k       Planck’s.. universelle Constante k 
 Ehrenfest       1911.07   1911       k       –– 
 Planck          1911.07   1911c      k    S  der universelle Faktor k 9 
 Debye           1911.08   1911       k    S  constante de la loi de Boltzmann 
 Ornstein        1911.09   1911  (f)  R/N  R  –– 
 Sommerfeld      1911.09   1911       k    E  –– 
 Perrin          1911.11   1912       r    R  la constante universelle R/N 
 Langevin        1911.11   1912       k       le coefficient de Boltzmann 
 Debye           1911.12   1912a      k    S  universelle Konstante, mit welcher.. 
 K.Onnes-Keesom• 1911.12   1912       kP      Planck’sche Konstante 
 Lorentz                   1912       k    E  une constante universelle 
 Planck          1912.01   1912       k    S  –– 
 Einstein        1912.01   1912       ϰ       –– (ambiguous!) 
 Bohr            1912.02   1912       k    R  gas-constant referred to a molecule 
 Kroò            1912.02   1912       k       die universelle Plancksche Konstante 
 Warburg         1912.02   1912       k       Plancksche Strahlungskonstante 
 Debye           1912.03   1912b      k       constante universelle de Boltzmann 
 Tetrode         1912.03   1912       k    S  –– 
 Frank           1912.04   1912       k    U  –– 
 Keesom          1912.04   1912       kP      –– 
 Debye           1912.07   1912c      k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Drude-Boll•               1912       k    S  une constante universelle 
 Schrödinger     1912.10   1912       k       die Boltzmann-Planck-Konstante 8 
 Schrödinger     1912.10   1912       k       die universelle Boltzmannkonstante 
 Westphal        1912.10   1912       k    S  die Konstante der Entropiegleichung 
 Nernst•         1912.11   1913  (e)  ––      –– (school using β = h/k instead) 
 Planck•         1912.11   1913  (e)  k    S  universelle Integrationskonstante 
 Lorentz•        1912.11   1916       k    E  constante qui détermine l’énergie
 Born-von Kármán 1912.11   1913       k    U  –– 
 Hasenöhrl       1912.12   1913       k    S  –– 
 Reiche          1912.12   1913       k    U  –– 
 Jellinek•       1913.01   1913       k    S  eine universelle Konstante 
 Einstein-Stern  1913.01   1913       k    U  –– 
 Tetrode         1913.01   1913       k    U  –– 
 Sommerfeld      1913.02   1913       k    E  –– 
 Born-Bolza & al 1913.02   1913       k       die Plancksche universelle Konstante 
 Einstein        1913.03   1913       R/N  R  –– 
 Born                      1913       k    U  –– 
 Planck          1913.04   1913       k    U  –– 
 Planck          1913.04   1914       k    E  absolute Gaskonstante 
 Debye           1913.04   1914       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Smoluchowski    1913.04   1914       H/N  R  –– 
 Sommerfeld      1913.04   1914       k       die Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 Lorentz         1913.04   1914a      k    E  –– 
 Stern           1913.05   1913       k    R  –– 
 Ehrenfest       1913.05   1913       k    U  –– 
 Ratnowsky       1913.05   1913       k       die Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 Millikan        1913.06   1913  (g)  k       the Boltzmann entropy constant 
 Bolza           1913.07   1913       k       die Plancksche universelle Konstante 
 Born-Courant    1913.07   1913       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Debye           1913.07   1913a      k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Ortvay          1913.07   1913       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Debye           1913.08   1913b      k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Kroò            1913.09   1913       k       die Plancksche Konstante 
 Lorentz         1913.09   1914b      R/N  R  –– 
 Einstein                  1915       R/N  R  –– 
 von Laue        1913.10   1913       ϰ       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Fokker          1913.10   1913       k    S  de gasconstante voor één molecuul 
 von Laue        1913.10   1921       k       la constante de Boltzmann 
 Sommerfeld      1913.10   1921a      k    U  constante du rayonnement 
 Lorentz         1913.10   1921       k       la constante k de M. Planck 
 Einstein        1913.11   1913       k    S  –– 
 Schrödinger     1913.11   1913       k       Boltzmann-konstante 
 Schrödinger     1913.11   1914       k       Boltzmannkonstante 
 Pockels                   1913       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Stern           1914.02   1914       k    R  –– 
 Bragg           1914.03   1914       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Richardson•     1914.05   1914a      k    S  a universal constant 
 Griffiths       1914.06   1914       k       Boltzmann’s constant 
 Lorentz         1914.09   1917       k       Planck’s well known coefficient 
 Richardson                1914b      R    R  the gas constant for one molecule 
 Lindemann       1914.12   1915       R/n  R  –– 
 Czukor          1915.02   1915       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Tetrode         1915.02   1915  (e)  k       de constante van Planck 
 Richardson      1915.04   1915       k       Boltzmann’s constant 
 Richardson                1915       k       Boltzmann’s constant 
 Guillaume                 1915       k    R  la constante d’énergie moléculaire 
 von Laue        1915.05   1915a      k    S  –– 
 von Laue•       1915.07   1915b      k    S  –– 
 Born            1915.07   1915       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Rubens          1915.07   1915       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Planck          1915.11   1915       k    E  –– 
 Mandersloot     1915.11   1916       K       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Kroò            1915.11   1915       k    U  –– 
 Planck          1915.11   1915       k       –– 
 Jeans•          1916.01   1916       R    S  the universal gas-constant 
 Stern           1916.02   1916       k    R  –– 
 Gerlach         1916.04   1916       k    U  die universelle Konstante k 
 Wolfke          1916.04   1916       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Stern           1916.08   1916       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Einstein        1916.08   1916       ϰ    S  –– 
 Debye                     1916       k       die Boltzmann’sche Konstante 
 Einstein                  1916       k       die bekannte Boltzmann’sche Konstante 
 Hertz                     1916       k       die Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante`

`•` $=$ textbook or reference book. `(e|f|g)` $=$ English | French | German translation.
Letters `S|U|R|E` tell the formula each article *not* naming $k$ uses to first introduce it:
$$
S=k\log W\qquad\quad
U=\frac{h\nu}{e^{\frac{h\nu}{kT}}-1}\qquad\quad
R=Nk\qquad\quad
E=\tfrac32kT.
$$

Notes (in progress, very much open to debate / correction):

<sup>1</sup> First known occurrence of the principle. (Quoted by Planck 1900b.)
<sup>2</sup> First known occurrence of the constant. (Ever quoted?)
<sup>3</sup> First known occurrence of the formula. (Ever quoted?)
<sup>4</sup> Earli(est?) to call the principle Boltzmann’s.
<sup>5</sup> Earli(est?) to call the constant Boltzmann’s.
<sup>6</sup> Earli(est?) to call the formula Boltzmann’s.
<sup>7</sup> Earli(est?) to call the constant Planck’s.
<sup>8</sup> Earli(est?) to call the constant Boltzmann-Planck’s.
<sup>9</sup> Calls the constant ***not*** Boltzmann’s.

Comment: I have found an earlier (earliest?) reference to Boltzmann's constant: Paul Ehrenfest, [Zur Planckschen Strahlungstheorie](https://ilorentz.org/IL-publications/sources/Ehrenfest_06e.pdf),
Physikalische Zeitschrift **7**: 528-532 (1906): In paragraph 3 he writes _Boltzmannschen Konstante k_ when referring to the average kinetic energy per molecule $\frac{3}{2}kT$.

Comment: Great — you may very well have found the original proponent of “Boltzmann’s constant”. Interestingly, Ehrenfest seems to have rarely repeated this, e.g. it’s not in his Boltzmann obituary 3 months later. Nor did anyone else (that I could find) until much later: Debye (1912), Born, von Laue (1913); experimentalists even slower. I added some — note especially who said what at the Wolfskehl & Solvay conferences (April & October 1913). I wonder when Sommerfeld switched, and whether his *Atombau und Spektrallinien* was the first textbook to do so. Can anyone find a copy of the first edition (1919)?

Comment: It is of interest to note that [Mehra and Rechenberg](https://books.google.nl/books?id=AwmQTGB8LwMC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=letter+from+planck+after+boltzmann%27s+death&source=bl&ots=P1l9yDG9x1&sig=X3LZOTEXR7EmA2dMQ1vHZ6jc8KA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisjrjLwebYAhULLcAKHe5tCfkQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false) (volume 5, page 98) refer to this paper of Ehrenfest as "the official point of view of Boltzmann's institute in 1906". Note also that it was submitted by Ehrenfest in July, _before_ Boltzmann's death in September, so the name "Boltzmann's constant" was not coined in response to that tragic event.

Comment: Speaking of representing Vienna: Hasenöhrl did that at the Solvay meetings of both 1911.11 and 1913.10. One might hope that the campaign described in his booklet left possibly interesting traces in *letters* by some of the protagonists... but I don’t know where to look for it. (So far only found [these](http://sommerfeld.userweb.mwn.de/WissDat/01633.html) by Debye, Ehrenfest.)

Comment: Am I right to question the translation of Einstein 1912.01? To me [Einführung der Planckschen Konstante**n**](//einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol4-doc/142) sounds plural, i.e. he’s introducing h = / and  = R/N and calling ***both*** Planck’s. (That surprised me, as I was already picturing him as likely behind his friend Kowalski’s switch between 1908 and 1909.) Then again, it [seems](//books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=der+Planckschen+Konstante%2Cder+Planckschen+Konstanten&corpus=20) it could also be [singular](//google.com/books?id=gQtJAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Planckschen+Konstanten%22)?

Comment: I asked at https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41361/31745 --- with an answer that confirms "der Planckschen Konstanten" as grammatically correct genitive singular, see also https://www.dwds.de/wb/Konstante

Comment: I see, substantivized adjective can explain it — and wow, they prove it with an example *by the same author* ! So grammar alone won’t decide either way, and I’ll remove the attribution. Maybe he even *wanted* to leave it ambiguous while “answering” Warburg, who at the time definitely called both constants Planck’s (1912.02)... (Just next to those and after Solvay 1911 where they *all* met, I’m sure there must be more from [Kamerlingh Onnes et al](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000677835), but won’t be able to look into it for a while.)

Comment: Re Ehrenfest: Leiden’s Boerhaave apparently has all his [diaries](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/4943663)... Not online, are they? They could hold interesting remarks, e.g. M. J. Klein’s [quotes](https://google.com/books?id=YIRGAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22arrived+at+Gottingen+on+Saturday%22) already show that he attended and commented on the 1913 Wolfskehl conference, which to me looks increasingly like a turning point (where e.g. [Debye](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=mdp.39015021268936&num=259) may have influenced Kamerlingh Onnes-Keesom to drop that $k_{\mathrm P}$).

Answer (score 4):

**Q: When did the name “Boltzmann constant” prevail, and how?**

In Herzfeld's review article from 1920 for the [Encyklopädie der Mathematischen Wissenschaften](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-663-16016-8_12) the symbol $k$ is called Boltzmann's constant without further discussion, so this must have been common usage at that time. This implies that there is no connection with Boltzmann's tombstone, which is from 1933 (as described [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=iIyKTjZLEc8C&pg=PA231)).

Tetrode in his 1912 [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19123430708) still refers to Planck's constant (and makes a point that his $\ln$ is Planck's $\log$), so the formula $S=k\log W$ was still a novelty.

I would conclude that the transition from Planck's constant to Boltzmann's constant happened in the 1912-1920 time frame.

Concerning the role of Lorentz in the naming of the constant, I note that in a 1917 paper entitled *Some remarks on the theory of monatomic gases*, Lorentz refers to $k$ as "Planck's well-known coefficient" ([online](http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00012398.pdf), page 47). I did not find a later reference from Lorentz, however, in the Ph.D. thesis of his student Van de Sande Bakhuyzen, from 1921, the constant $k$ is called "Boltzmann's constant" ([online](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/IL-publications/dissertations/sources/vandeSandeBakhuyzen_1921.pdf), page 39).$^*$

So this is consistent with the idea that the name Boltzmann constant emerged within a few years before 1920.

---

One might ask what prompted the switch from Planck constant to Boltzmann constant. This screen shot from Van de Sande Bakhuyzen's Ph.D. thesis suggests the obvious answer: once quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics came together, a single formula would contain both $h$ and $k$ and different names were needed.

[image]

---

$^*$ I also searched for references to Boltzmann's constant in other Ph.D. theses of Lorentz's students (online [here](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/IL-publications/dissertations/lorentz.html)):

- [Fokker](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/IL-publications/dissertations/sources/Fokker_1913.pdf)
  (1913): calls $k$ the single-molecule gas constant (page 20)
- [Bruins](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/IL-publications/dissertations/sources/Bruins_1918.pdf)
  (1918): uses the symbol $s$ instead of $k$ and calls it the gas constant of a molecule (page 92)
- [van
  Slingelandt](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/IL-publications/dissertations/sources/vanSlingelandt_1919.pdf) (1919): on page 39 writes $\eta =\frac{R}{N}\log W$ and calls it
  the "principle of Boltzmann", but without introducing a separate
  notation for $R/N$.
- [van de Sande Bakhuyzen](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/IL-publications/dissertations/sources/vandeSandeBakhuyzen_1921.pdf) (1921) finally calls $k$ the "constant of Boltzmann" (page 39).

So 1920 seems to be the "phase transition" year, at least for Lorentz's students.

Comment: Ha, I had no idea the tombstone formula was this late. There is another monument ([1912](https://monuments.univie.ac.at/index.php?title=Denkmal_Ludwig_Boltzmann)) with remarks by his successor Hasenöhrl ([1913](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/263101318)), apparently not found online. From Leiden, can you say more on ter Haar’s claim that Lorentz kept calling both constants Planck’s? What I found (e.g. Solvay 1913, footnote [p. 283](https://archive.org/stream/lastructuredelam00inst#page/283)) is not so clear cut, but his [collected works](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/1279988) may have more...

Comment: I found a reference to Planck's coefficient in a 1917 paper by Lorentz, and a reference to Boltzmann's constant in the 1923 Ph.D. thesis of his last student, so the switch must have happened in that time frame.

Comment: Ah, that Hasenöhrl booklet of 1913 is actually [online](http://phaidra.univie.ac.at/o:170477) (linked by German Wikipedia). He writes on p.15: “When the idea arose to build Boltzmann a monument in our university’s arcade courtyard, a distinguished expert proposed to decorate it with the formula $S=k.\log W$. That would go against our university’s customs and may be superfluous, as the discovery itself is a monumentum aere perennius.” Also reproduced is an early 1911 “call to build” signed by 100+ physicists including Einstein, Lorentz, Nernst, Planck, Rutherford, Sommerfeld, Zeeman .../...

Comment: ... at least some of whom must have read, and perhaps been (one way or the other) influenced by, the idea Hasenöhrl is floating here. This and your other references put me on track to more, that I will next try to post in some sort of chronology. Do you know what (if anything) Lorentz’s earlier students were calling $k$?

Comment: I listed the Tetrode paper as not naming the constant, because unless I missed it, he’s only crediting Planck for its numerical value. Also, van Slingelandt actually introduces k — pp. 5, 8, 13, as “the constant which determines the average kinetic energy of a molecule at temperature T, which energy equals 3/2 kT.” (So far as I can tell, he doesn’t call it a name, nor mentions that R/N of page 39 is the same thing.)

Comment: Oh! Sommerfeld ([1947](//doi.org/10.1002/andp.19484380104)) *identifies himself* as the expert who proposed engraving S = k log W on the 1912 bust. (He adds — quoting 1877 *not* 1898: “Planck, in the wonderful exposition he gave of the relation between entropy and probability in his radiation theory book, had emphasized Boltzmann’s merit so much that the reader gets the impression that it’s all excerpted from Boltzmann’s works. Only much later did I convince myself that neither the constant k, nor the formula S = k log W which we now call “Boltzmann's Principle”, occur in Boltzmann himself.”)

Comment: I understand that Sommerfeld proposed this around 1906 (but the engraving was initially rejected and only realized in 1912); the "much later" could then refer to the years between 1906 and 1911 (because Sommerfeld still called $k$ "Planck's" constant in 1911).

Comment: I believe it went slower. According to Hasenöhrl’s 1913 booklet (p. 3), a 5-year rule forbid any monument before 1911, so the committee to set things in motion was formed in Spring 1910 and issued its call to build in early 1911. The way I read it, Sommerfeld’s proposal happened during either the 1910 collection of signatures or the 1911-12 collection of monies, and “much later” should be much after that. There was no engraving in 1912, only 1933. (Did that whole collection operation really leave no trace in anyone’s correspondence?)

Comment: I was referring to Sommerfeld's remark that "In den Arkaden  ist die vorgeschlagene Unterschrift  nicht angebracht worden, da sie den dortigen Gepflogenheiten widersprochen hatte.  Aber sie ist einige Jahre spater von dem Bildhauer wieder aufgenommen.." I would interpret this that Sommerfeld's suggestion was several years before the monument was actually realized.

Comment: Yes, but his “einige Jahre später” refers to the Zentralfriedhof monument (1933). So I read “erst sehr viel später habe ich mich überzeugt” as certainly after 1911, and likely even after 1933.

Answer (score 1):

#### Community-wiki timeline (continued, 1917–):

After 1920, a vast majority of papers call $k$ Boltzmann’s constant. So (with few exceptions) mention is only made of sources calling it another name, plus some textbooks and reference books.

`Author         |Dated    |Published |Denoted|Called 
 Millikan        1917.01   1917       k    S  the entropy constant 
 Schrödinger               1917       R/N  R  –– 
 Gerlach         1917.08   1918       k    S  die Konstante der Entropie 
 Flamm           1917.09   1917       k    S  die Entropiekonstante 
 Born            1917.10   1917       k       die Maxwell-Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Sommerfeld                1918       k    S  die Konstante k des Boltzmannschen Prinzips 
 Wien                      1918       k    S  die Entropiekonstante 
 von Laue        1918.07   1918       k    E  –– 
 Schrödinger     1918.07   1919       k    R  –– 
 Bruins          1918.07   1918       s    R  de gasconstante van een molecuul 
 von Laue        1918.08   1918       k       der Boltzmannsche k 
 Stern           1918.11   1919       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Reiche          1918.12   1919       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 von Laue        1918.12   1919       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante
 Lorentz•                  1919a      k    E  2/3 der translatie-energie per graad 
 Lorentz•                  1919b (e)  k       constante van Planck 
 Nernst-Wulf     1919.04   1919       k    R  Gaskonstante pro Molekül 
 Lindemann       1919.05   1919a      k       Boltzmann’s constant 
 Lindemann       1919.07   1919b      k       Boltzmann’s constant 
 Birge           1919.07   1919       k       the Boltzmann entropy constant 
 Sommerfeld•     1919.09   1919       ?       ? 
 Lindemann       1919.09   1920       k       Boltzmann’s constant 
 van Slingelandt 1919.12   1919       k    E  constante, die kinetische energie bepaalt 
 Stern           1919.12   1920       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Silberstein     1920.02   1920       k    U  constant in Planck’ formula 
 Lyon-Wolfram    1920.03   1920              die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Stern           1920.04   1920       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Ladenburg       1920.05   1920       k       die Boltzmannsche Entropiekonstante 
 Planck          1920.06   1920  (e)  k    U  die erste Strahlungskonstante 9 
 Sommerfeld•     1920.09   1921b (e)  k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Reiche•         1920.10   1921  (e)  k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Schaefer•       1920.10   1921       k    R  –– 
 Herzfeld•       1920.12   1920       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Haas•           1921.03   1921       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Gerlach                   1921       k       die Plancksche Entropiekonstante 
 V.d.S.Bakhuyzen 1921.12   1921       k       constante van Boltzmann 
 Gerlach-Stern   1922.04   1922       k    E  –– 
 Hertz                     1922       k       die Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 Eucken                    1922       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Henning                   1922       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Born•           1922.09   1923       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Lorentz•                  1923  (e)  k       constante van Planck 
 Darwin•                   1923       k    E  the atomic gas constant 
 Coblentz•                 1923       k       Boltzmann gas constant 
 Berliner & al•  1924.04   1924       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Einstein        1924.07   1924  (e)  ϰ    S  –– 
 Schrödinger     1924.11   1924       k       Boltzmannkonstante 
 Einstein        1925.01   1925a      ϰ       –– 
 Einstein        1925.01   1925b      ϰ       –– 
 Smekal•         1925.06   1926       k       Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 Smekal•         1925.06   1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Schrödinger     1925.12   1926  (e)  k       –– 
 Geiger-Scheel•            1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Henning-Jaeger•           1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Bennewitz•                1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Smekal•                   1926       k       die sog. Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 Byk•                      1926       k       die molekulare Gaskonstante 
 Jäger•                    1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Henning•                  1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Henning•                  1926       k       Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 Grüneisen•                1926       k       Plancksche Strahlungskonstante 
 van der Waals•            1926       k       –– 
 Schrödinger•              1926       k       –– 
 Simon•                    1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Gerlach•                  1926       R/N     –– 
 Pauli•                    1926       k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Ladenburg•                1926       k    U  die universelle Entropiekonstante 9 
 Franck-Jordan•            1926       k       Boltzmannsche Konstante 
 Guillaume & al•           1926       k    R  molecular gas constant 
 Tolman•         1926.08   1927       k    R  the Boltzmann constant 
 Uhlenbeck       1927.07   1927       k       constante van Boltzmann 
 Planck•         1930.03   1930  (e)  k    S  der universelle Faktor k 9 
 Berliner & al•  1931.11   1932       k       Boltzmann-Plancksche Konstante 
 (tombstone)     1933.07   1933       k    S  –– 
 Planck                    1943       k    S  meine Konstante k 9 
 van Dantzig     1939.06   1939       k       Boltzmann's number
 Planck          1945.03   1948  (e)  k    S  die sog. absolute Gaskonstante 9 
 Meissner                  1951       k       the Boltzmann-Planck constant 9 
 Sommerfeld•               1952  (e)  k       die Boltzmannsche Konstante 9,10`

`•` $=$ textbook or reference book. `(e)` $=$ English translation.

<sup>9</sup> Calls the constant ***not*** Boltzmann’s.
<sup>10</sup> Calls the formula ***not*** Boltzmann’s.

Comment: Split off from the other CW answer, as it was reaching the 30k character limit.