# In which work was Boltzmann's entropy originally introduced?

Tags: physics, reference-request, thermodynamics, boltzmann, entropy

I get an impression from [this enyclopedia entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/statphys-Boltzmann/#Aca)

that the primary source of the Boltzmann entropy equation $S = k \log W$ might be

> 1866, Über die Mechanische Bedeutung des Zweiten Hauptsatzes der Wärmetheorie, Wiener Berichte, 53: 195–220; in WA I, paper 2.

I cannot read German. The only PDF I was able to obtain did not have a text-layer, so I could not copy-paste parts into Google Translate. Eventually I might go through and hand-type the whole thing into Google translate, but in the interim I would appreciate assistance expediting my search.

What is the original source of the Boltzmann entropy equation?

Comment: The introduction of the linked publication states "The intended purpose of this paper is to provide a purely analytical, completely generalized proof of the second law of thermodynamics, as well as identify a corresponding law of mechanics." During a *quick* perusal of the paper, I did not spot anything that corresponds to the entropy equation, but may have overlooked it.

Comment: I don't have time to follow up right now, but the relevant publication *may* be: L. Boltzmann, "Über die Beziehung zwischen dem zweiten Hauptsatz der mechanischen Wärmetheorie und der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung respektive den Sätzen über das Wärmegleichgewicht", *Wiss. Abhandlungen*, Band II, p. 163-223 (1877). In other words, it is to be found in volume 2 of his collected works. Right now I have no idea about the original publication venue.

Comment: One source I consulted claims that the simple entropy formula given in the question is due to Planck and cannot be found in this form in any of Boltzmann's works. *Supposedly* the closest equation in a publication by Boltzmann is found on [page 172](https://books.google.com/books?id=RC45DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR3&ots=rnZ74XWv8F&dq=Boltzmann%20Vorlesungen%20zur%20Gastheorie&lr&pg=PA172#v=onepage) of *Vorlesungen über Gastheorie: 2. Teil*, 1898 (tr.: Lectures on gas theory, part 2). There we find $S = R M l \mathfrak{W}$, where $l$ denotes the natural logarithm and $M$ is the mass of a hydrogen atom.

Comment: Related question: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/interpretation-of-w-in-boltzmanns-entropy-formula?rq=1